# jQuery deep linking plugins (#hash navigation)

Tags: jquery, web-applications, jquery-plugins, deep-linking

So far I've found Address (port of SWFaddress?) and BBQ. Which other plugins that provide this functionality exist, and which is better/standard?

So far I've only built my own hackish #-reading scripts, but need something that can handle multiple variables, i.e. #user=bob&sortBy=rating.

Any suggestions or opinions are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWFAddress and BBQ are both good. If you want to continue to do it on your own, you can use both `window.location.hash` and `window.location.search` for the `#` and the query string respectively.

For example:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var qs = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&"); // this is an array for the QS
```

That's a bit hacky and for a more robust solution for the query string, you can check out [Querystring](http://adamv.com/dev/javascript/querystring)

Comment: Could you explain very briefly what the main difference(s) between BBQ and Address are?

Comment: They're just separate solutions to the same problem: the allow you to access the query string and URL hash tags and well as keep a state history be leverages changes to the URL. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/ & http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Comment: I just ran into an issue where SWFAddress was already included in a page, and I used BBQ to set/access values from the hash. Both coexist peacefully, until IE9 enters the picture… Apparently SWFAddress includes IE specific code that adds a backslash to the beginning of the hash value. BBQ read this added backslash as part of the key. So `#step=2` became `#/step=2` after SWFAddress ran its course, and BBQ returned `{ '/step': 2 }`. Caveat emptor.